# what does "-Bdynamic" compilation flag does?

Tags: c++, c, dynamic-compilation

I was reading Intel Inspector XE 2013 documentation, and they have mentioned setting of flag "-Bdynamic". Can anyone please tell me what does this flag do ?
I have searched the gnu compilation options but have not seen this.

Thanks,
Sheeri

Comment: To dynamically link the libraries.

Comment: What did you searched, exactly? The [first result from google](https://www.google.it/search?espv=210&es_sm=91&q=Bdynamic&oq=Bdynamic&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i10i30i19j0i7i30i19l9.5082.5082.0.5467.1.1.0.0.0.0.195.195.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.32.serp..0.1.194.eSH0WKIojfM) explains it.

Comment: I searched for "-Bdynamic" compilation flag but google did not answer correct results. I guess my search query  syntax was misleading.

Comment: since your qeury term `"-Bdynamic` starts with a dash `-` google **excluded** it from results - https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en

Comment: @Jefffrey your link cleverly omits the dash without explaining the need to do that - not everyone is as clever as you

Comment: just a thought--wouldnt keeping the search tag within quotes facilitate the whole string search ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

assume you have both a shared library: `libabc.so` and a static library: `libabc.a` in the same directory referenced by -L and using `-labc` to specify the library:

with `-Bdynamic` it will use `libabc.so`

with `-Bstatic` it will use `libabc.a`